# Split a single data frame into multiple data frames based on a columns value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that has thousands of rows in a Jupyter Notebook using Pandas. I am attempting to use a particular column in this data frame to split the df into multiple dfs based on the columns values. If there is a way to do this without specifying the different values in the column explicitly, that would be great.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dat1 | Val1 | etc1 | set1 |
| dat2 | Val2 | etc2 | set2 |
| dat3 | Val3 | etc3 | set2 |
| dat4 | Val4 | etc4 | set3 |

An example of one of the variations of my code:

```
NAM_df2 = NAM_df1.loc[NAM_df1["Col4"] == 'set2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dfs = [d for _, d in df.groupby('Col4')]
```

Comment: does this convert my single df into a list? There was an error message when I went to view the dfs using dfs.head(). "list object has no attribute head"

Comment: Yes, it does. Is that not what you wanted? I'm sorry, it wasn't perfectly obvious what you wanted. Please clarify :)

Comment: My apologies. Asking the question the right way seems more complicated than piecing together an answer sometimes. The goal is to take a single df and split it into multiple dfs based on the value in a particular column. In the example above, based on 'Col4' values I would want to take the 1 df and make 3 dfs from it since there are 3 different values in Col4 to group by

Comment: That's what this code does, actually. This code splits the dataframe by all the unique values in `Col4`, so if `Col4` has values `1 2 2 2 4 5 5`, `dfs` will contains 4 dataframes, each containing all of the rows with a particular value (the first will contain all (1) the rows where `Col4` is `1`, the second will contain all (3) rows where `Col4` is `2`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
df1s = [df.loc[df['Col1']==x, :] for x in df['Col1'].unique()]
df4s = [df.loc[df['Col4']==x, :] for x in df['Col4'].unique()]
```